# Comments go under Ads / Text wrapping problem

Tags: bug, design

I'm using Chrome on a 13" Chromebook with large font settings.

My problem is I get text wrapping problems after I use `add / show X more comments`.

[image: comments go under Ads]

Comment: I believe that the response to similar reports has been "if you use a custom font we can't be held responsible for it breaking anything". Got to find that question though...

Comment: If so, not supporting a stock device would be very customer unfriendly.

Comment: and funny thing I should add, %20 of the horizontal screen real estate is just padding - probably that's also the cause.

Comment: I too am experiencing the same problem.  In Chrome's advanced settings I have the Minimum font size set to 14.  Screen size is not the issue.  I can maximize the browser on a 22” monitor and it still does it.  I wonder if there is anything that can be done to bring attention to this issue.